# i have erorr when sendTransaction web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, metamask

file javascript

```
//smartcontract
    window.onload = function() {
        if (typeof web3 === 'undefined') {
            document.getElementById('metamask').innerHTML = 'Instal metamask dulu'
        }
    }
    var abi = [
        {
            "constant": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "_judul",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "_content",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ],
            "name": "addArtikel",
            "outputs": [],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "artikel",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "judul",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "content",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "penulis",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "timestamp",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        },
        {
            "constant": true,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "name": "penulisPost",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "judul",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "content",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "penulis",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "name": "timestamp",
                    "type": "uint256"
                }
            ],
            "payable": false,
            "stateMutability": "view",
            "type": "function"
        }
    ]

var contractaddress = '0x9b67c76A53517A7985367e240343DDA6Ad2dBE81'
var _abi = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var _function = _abi.at(contractaddress);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnTambah").click(function(){
        _function.addArtikel.sendTransaction($("#judul").val(), {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4000000});
    });
});
```

my smartcontract

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract blog {

// content post
struct Posting {
    string judul;
    string content;
    address penulis;
    uint256 timestamp;
}

mapping(address => Posting[]) public penulisPost;

Posting[] public artikel;

// tambah artikel

function addArtikel(string memory _judul, string memory _content) public {
   Posting memory post = Posting(_judul, _content,  msg.sender, now);
   penulisPost[msg.sender].push(post);
    artikel.push(post);
    }
}
```

**MY ERORR**

```
Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_sendTransaction without a callback parameter. See https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client for details.
    at MetamaskInpageProvider._sendSync (inpage.js:1)
    at MetamaskInpageProvider.send (inpage.js:1)
    at Proxy.h.(:8887/online/anonymous function) (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:3202)
    at a.send (inpage.js:1)
    at n.e [as sendTransaction] (inpage.js:1)
    at u.sendTransaction (inpage.js:1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:100)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Hi there. What is the error?

Comment: Declare function `addArtikel` as `public payable`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your parameters. Web3.eth.sendTransaction: web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject [, callback])

Your error message specifies the lack of a callback. Additionally, I'm not sure what `$("#judul").val()` is for you, but likely needs to be assigned in the transactionObjec, which is the first parameter